# Is there a way to list every windows processes from cpp?

Tags: c++, windows, process

I'm recently looking to list every processes of a machine to do some action. But I'm struggling with processes which are not launched from my user (eg: system, administrator or an other user).

I tried some codes and some solutions but there is still anything who works.

I am working on the code proposed by microsoft to enumerate all the processes.

Here is the code :

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <psapi.h>

// To ensure correct resolution of symbols, add Psapi.lib to TARGETLIBS
// and compile with -DPSAPI_VERSION=1

void PrintProcessNameAndID( DWORD processID )
{
    TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");

    // Get a handle to the process.

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                                   PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                   FALSE, processID );

    // Get the process name.

    if (NULL != hProcess )
    {
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeeded;

        if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), 
             &cbNeeded) )
        {
            GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName, 
                               sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );
        }
    }

    // Print the process name and identifier.

    _tprintf( TEXT("%s  (PID: %u)\n"), szProcessName, processID );

    // Release the handle to the process.

    CloseHandle( hProcess );
}

int main( void )
{
    // Get the list of process identifiers.

    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
    {
        return 1;
    }


    // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.

    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    // Print the name and process identifier for each process.

    for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
    {
        if( aProcesses[i] != 0 )
        {
            PrintProcessNameAndID( aProcesses[i] );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code works but does not allow you to view the processes of other users. Do you have an idea?

Thanks everyone for your time.
Regards

Comment: Does your program work if you run it in elevated mode - as admin?

Comment: What do you mean by *does not allow you to view the processes of other users*? You do not even get their processID or you just cannot get their name?

Comment: It's unlikely for you to get `PROCESS_VM_READ` access to processes launched by other users. You'd have gotten this much information already had you done even just basic error handling.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The name of every process ran from another user would be "<unknown>". So I can't get the process name if I doesn't know the PID.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That doesn't work because It's gonna catch only processes from admin user.

Comment: @mrRobot II was _asking_ if it works if you run it as admin. If the answer is _no_, why would it work the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

As a normal user, you are not going to get far by using `OpenProcess` on processes you don't own. If you elevate your process and enable the debug privilege you might have more luck. You will probably still be denied access to DRM and AntiVirus processes. In general the PSAPI functions expect a lot of access to the process with `PROCESS_VM_READ` being the biggest issue, Windows is not going to grant you memory read access to all other processes. Some of the newer APIs like `GetProcessImageFileName` have been upgraded (in Vista+) to only require `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` which you might be able to get for more processes.

I would suggest using the [Toolhelp API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/tool-help-library) instead, it should provide a little more info than `EnumProcesses`+`OpenProcess`. You can also get some information from the Performance Counters and WMI.

As a side note; `EnumProcesses` is the most useless API ever. It uses the NT API to get information about all processes then throws away all that information except the process ids.

If you are willing to use undocumented stuff, the NT Query/Information functions will give you more information than any documented API.

Answer (score 0):

The most reasonable solution I think would be to use
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot
You can do some looking up on it at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot

Heres a small example

```
HANDLE hProcessSnap;
PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    std::cout << "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (of processes) failed with error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return;

pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
if (!Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
{
    std::cout << "Failed getting first process" << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);          
    return;
}
do
{
    std::cout << "Process: " << pe32.szExeFile << std::endl;
} while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));
CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
```